# Why are grid items placed in rows by default?

Tags: css, css-grid

What makes them behave like this initially? What properties, what is happening here?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(32, 156, 88);
  display: grid;
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: rgb(226, 228, 131);
  border: 1px solid rgb(41, 135, 151);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no columns specified in the grid container.

```
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(32, 156, 88);
  display: grid;
}
```

Therefore, the container defaults to ONE column.

More precisely, the container is applying [`grid-auto-columns: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns), which is the default setting for implicit (i.e., undefined) columns.

The grid items are just stacking in this single column.

[image]

The items are also in rows because another default setting–[`grid-auto-flow: row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)– which sets the placement flow of items, is applied.

If you reverse this setting with `grid-auto-flow: column`, the items will line up in one row, because of the default `grid-auto-rows: auto`.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(32, 156, 88);
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: rgb(226, 228, 131);
  border: 1px solid rgb(41, 135, 151);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

There are various ways to create grid columns, including `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-areas` and [line-based placement](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement).

Answer (score -2):

Its because by default there is only one column and justify-content makes all columns take up the whole available space. Interesting when I will stop answering my own question...

Comment: Well no, by default there are no columns. The grid placement algorithm causes the creation of one column in your particular case,

Comment: and because the default flow (define by grid-auto-flow) is row so the browser will create as much rows as needed for your items. If you change the flow, you will have something different

Answer (score -2):

using grid-template-columns or grid-template-rows beside of class

> display:grid

is required.
for example you can do this to change to 3 colums:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
 grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;
  background-color: rgb(32, 156, 88);
  display: grid;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to add `grid-template-columns: repeat(/*Items per row*/, /* Width per item */);` to your .wrapper in your css